# Pings from outside to my router's interface ip address despite ACL rules

Tags: cisco, acl

I have access-list on my router like this:

```
access-list 101 permit ip 10.1.130.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.1.1.25
access-list 101 deny ip any any log
```

And interface ip address is like this:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address 10.1.130.254 255.255.255.0
ip access-group 101 in
```

As I understand, only `host 10.1.1.25` will be able to ping all my network from outside. 

But, on other outside routers (branches), all IPs with full access can ping `10.1.130.254`

Why IPs with full access can ping my router's interface ip address despite the `deny ip any any` in the end of ACL?

PS: All routers are cisco. They can ping only interface ip address, but not whole network.

Comment: Which IP ranges are considered "outside", what is "inside"? Is there more than one router interface involved? Remember that ACLs are *unidirectional*, and source/dest definitions in an ACL must be set the exact way the ip packet is seen *in the given direction* on the interface to which you bind the ACL.

Comment: there are 2 interfaces. Outside interface and insider interface on router. Outside ip addresses are: all ip addresses except 10.1.130.0/24 network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your ACL direction is IN, this will filter traffic coming in from your Lan.

This will allow traffic from your Lan 10.1.130.0 255.255.255.0 to access 10.1.1.25

As Ron stated your direction is wrong, it would need to be

```
ip access-group 101 out
```

But, if that were the case you would also need to, change your source and destination around

```
access-list 101 permit ip host 10.1.1.25 10.1.130.0 0.0.0.255
```

When considering the ACL direction, always think of standing in the middle of the router, and you are looking OUT an interface or the traffic is looking IN

Dont think of your traffic as OUT Wan and in Lan

Answer (score 0):

Your ACL is backwards. Swap the source and destination addresses (and masks).

Comment: No, ACL is not backwards. It filters IN traffic to internal interface of router. LAN is 10.1.130.0/24. LAN is going in the IN direction to router interface. And then, after that, it goes to outside interface with OUT direction.

Comment: My question is still the same. Why ips with full access on other routers (branch network) can ping my router's interface ip address 10.1.130.254?

Comment: For example, in branch office, ip address with 10.1.1.45 can ping 10.1.130.254. In branch office's router there is ACL with "permit ip host 10.1.1.45 any"

Comment: It’s backwards. The first address is the source address and the second is the destination address of the packet

Comment: it is not backwards. Source is my network and destination is branch network.

Answer (score 0):

The router is processing the ping request and replying to all devices because the `in` ACL doesn't apply to traffic sourced from the router.

Also Ron's answer is a best practice, but won't fix this issue.  You want to drop all traffic that will be denied closest to the source, not after the source has reached your protected device and you are only dropping the reply packet.

Answer (score 0):

The extended access list syntax is described below.

`Access-list <number 100-199> <permit | deny> <protocol> <source> < sourcemask>
<operator source port> < destination> <destination-mask> < operator destination port> <options> < log>`

So as per you access list the source and destination interface are inaccurate, they need to be swapped for it to work

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this: 
Access list I provided filters only IN traffic, but it does not refer to router's interface ip address. 
So, from outside, anyone with full access can ping only my router's ip address. 
It means that router's interface ip address considered as OUT address. 
 
The possible solutions: 
1. Use both IN and OUT access-lists on the interface. 
2. Use ACLs on vty (telnet, etc.) interfaces.